# Are there memory related issued with Java 8 upgrade on a spark cluster?

Tags: java, apache-spark, java-8, cloudera, permgen

We re recently upgrade our cluster to Java 8. Since them we are experiencing "Jave heap space" errors on spark jobs. We are aware of of removal of PermGen memory space in Java 8. What are the implications of this for spark jobs?

Also are there any other Java 8 related effects on Spark jobs?

We are using spark 1.6 as part of cloudera distribution.

We build a fat job and submit the job with the following parameters:

spark-submit --class prediction \
    --master yarn-client \
    --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=600 \
    --conf spark.executor.memory=7g \
    --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512m" \
    ./target/scala-2.10/predicition-assembly-1.0.jar

Part of the code that is causing this issue is a spark-sql dataframe related grouping and aggregation

```
val data = sessions
  .join(mapping, mapping(id1) === sessions(id1))
  .join(p, mapping(id) === p(id))
  .groupBy(mapping(id)
    , unixToHourOfDayWithTimeZone(sessions(msts),p(timezone))
    , unixToDayOfWeekWithTimeZone(sessions(msts), p(timeZone))
  )
  .agg(count(sessions(msts)).alias(GenericCount)
    , avg(sessions(s))
  )
```

Comment: How are you submitting your spark jobs? What are "Java heap space" errors and when do they occur? You have to be more specific and post a [MCVE] in order for us to help you.

Comment: Thanks. I will update the question